# Defunct processes while running Selenium webdrivers

Tags: server, python, selenium

I have an issue with selenium webdrivers (both Firefox and Chrome) running on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS.

There is an 24/7 webpage monitoring Python script running on the server described higher and this script uses webdriver. After some time (I haven't found any regularities) the system transforms the webdriver related processes into defunct ones so the script stops seeing any changes on page and may loose connection as a result (in case of Chromedriver).

The script keeps running without any exceptions.

Could you help me to figure out what causes this situation. Maybe I should disable some services like systemd-oomd for example? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: those defunct processes are zombie processes.  Only way to erase them is a reboot.  They are essentially already dead processes but didnt terminate in a way that would remove them from the processes list.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank you for the answer. Cannot grasp what causes them. I have noticed that Firefox webdriver produces less zombies than its Chrome counterpart.

Comment: its likely Selenium leavingbehind the dead processes.  However the dead processes shouldnt be taking up any resources other than an extra PID number so you orobably dont need to worry.  Or just reboot your system once in a while.

Comment: @ThomasWard I thought that the appearance of these zombies affects the script. Maybe I am wrong. Thanks. If I only be sure that rebooting of system once a day can help... I do it manually and it seems to have no effect (

Comment: Still cannot understand what is going on with that sever but I have found the solution that solved the problems above in pretty another way) Now I run Selenium Chrome as a docker container and connect to it from my script.